# How to disable username and password authentication in Squid proxy, centOS 7?

Tags: centos7, squid

I want to disable username and password authentication, because I have ACL by IP address. I don't want to bother user with password as well.

Comment: This might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828492/squid-how-to-disable-authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for particular group you can go into **squid.conf** and comment out for the users you don't want username and password

For Eg: -

```
#acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
#auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwd auth_param basic
```

**Modify** :

```
#acl foo proxy_auth REQUIRED

#http_access deny all
#http_access allow all
```

And then restarted squid

Hope this works for you

Comment: I don't have any comment with ncsa_users in squid.conf.